# Problema al usar un link de imagen desde un servidor nodejs usando React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base-de-datos, imagen, axios

tengo un problema que le he dado vueltas un buen rato y la verdad no entiendo cual puede ser el problema, tengo en un servidor almacenado algunos datos que además vienen con links de imagenes, puedo acceder a los textos sin ningún problema pero a la hora de utilizar el link de la imagen para mostrarla me da error, el error es "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')"

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function Producto() {

    const params = useParams()

    const [producto, setProducto] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProducto = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/productos')
            const filter = res.data.filter(e => e.url === params.id)
            const producto = filter[0]
            setProducto(producto)
        }
        getProducto()
    }, [])

  return (
    <img src={producto.imagen.url} alt={producto.imagen.url} />
  )
}

export default Producto
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, deberías de sacar la llamada a la api fuera del useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    getProducto()
}, [])

const getProducto = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/productos')
    const filter = res.data.filter(e => e.url === params.id)
    const producto = filter[0]
    setProducto(producto)
}
```

Segundo inicializas la variable producto como un array vacío y luego en getproducto y en el return es un objeto, deberías de inicializarla como un objeto vacío o a undefined.

El problema que tienes también es que cuando la llamada a la api termina mas tarde de que react renderice el componente, así primero intenta pintar la imagen cuando no tienes datos. Deberías de poner un renderizado condiciónal como este.

```
  return (
     producto && producto?.imagen?.url
        ? <img src={producto.imagen.url} alt={producto.imagen.url} />
        : <></>
```

)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por darte el tiempo de responder, me funciono perfecto todo, gracias!